# Android paste large text file into edittext

Tags: android

I have an app and I need users to be able to paste any amount of text into an edittext box. I would like users to be able to paste up to at least 100,000 words if possible. How can I accomplish this with android? Attaching a file isn't possible.

Here is the xml for my edittext if that helps.

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text=""
    android:minLines="2"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"

    />
```

And if it helps this is all I am doing with the edit text

```
final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            document = input.getText().toString();
```

Comment: is there any problem in pasting in edittext currently?

Comment: String text = ......; editText.setText(text); Thats all. What is the problem?

Comment: and what is the problem? is there any error, or what?

Comment: android:maxLines="6" if you set this how will it take 100,000 words if required? Remove that line. Use input.setText(<text from document>) to display the text in EditText.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. I did remove the max lines already, however the problem is that when holding down and hitting paste nothing happens. So I have to imagine there is some issue with the size limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the device I was using for testing couldn't handle the input.

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined limit for EditText.

You can only limit it manually `(android:maxLength="10")`